# choppy / laggy bluetooth mouse ubuntu 18

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

Bluetooth mouse is very choppy on Ubuntu 18 (and 16). My laptop is MacBook Pro. While USB mouse is working just great.

Comment: See my comment in this question https://askubuntu.com/a/1179244/1003126

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that worked well for me [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1860951#p1860951). You need to reduce the min poll time for Bluetooth devices. First, forget the mouse from Bluetooth settings, then set conn_min_latency like so:

```
sudo echo 6 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_min_interval
```

Reconnect the mouse and it should move smoothly. I have some suspicion that this is for improving battery life on my ultrabook, so be aware.