# Microsoft Bluetooth mouse 3600 lags in Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS

Tags: bluetooth, lts, microsoft

I have a microsoft bluetooth mouse 3600 which works fine under windows,
I've successfully connected to it under ubuntu, it works,
But lags in an annoying way....

Could this be fixed ?

I had it working fine at my desktop with ubuntu 16 LTS

Update: I'm no longer using Ubuntu, so can't test the solutions, thanks anyway.
I'll accept the available solution just to not be rude...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1824559/comments/10) helped me at the same situation.

You have to edit the following file:

```
sudo nano /var/lib/bluetooth/<MAC of BT adapter>/<MAC of BT Mouse>/info
```

At the end of the file, add the section:

```
[ConnectionParameters]
MinInterval=6
MaxInterval=7
Latency=0
Timeout=216
```

Finally, apply the changes:

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

Comment: I was not able to see the <MAC of BT Mouse> and so the file "info", due to permissions of these directories. So I used "sudo -i" to make sure I can see all the files. Other than this, the solution worked for me perfectly!